# Connect marker with EditPart

Tags: resources, marker, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef

I have a graphical editor which extends *GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette*.

There could be appear different markers, so it would be nice, if there is any possibility to connect the marker with the *EditPart*.

I think one possibility is to extend the *TableViewer* and the corresponding cell classes. But perhaps there is a better and more easier way.

I create my test markers like following:

```java
IResource resource = (IResource) input.getAdapter(IResource.class);

try 
{
    IMarker marker = resource.createMarker(IMarker.PROBLEM);
    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.TEXT, "text");
    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);
    marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, "message");
}
catch (CoreException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**input** is my *IEditorInput*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my first attempt, I was trying to extends the *ExtendedMarkersView*, which fails because it is an internal class.
Another way was to write the view and all corresponding stuff new, but it seems to be senseless.

So I found a work around based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/10501971/390177.
While creating the *IMarker*, I set additional attributes to link the corresponding data object. With the help of the object I can search for the *AbstractGraphicalEditPart* with the *EditPartRegistry*.
After that it is possible to create a selection on the *EditPart* and reveal to it.

```
@Override
public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection) {
    IStructuredSelection s = (IStructuredSelection) selection;

    if (s.getFirstElement() instanceof MarkerItem) {
        MarkerItem marker = (MarkerItem) s.getFirstElement();
        if (marker != null && marker.getMarker() != null) {
            IMarker iMarker = marker.getMarker();
            AbstractGraphicalEditPart editPart = null;

            DataObject object ...
            editPart = (AbstractGraphicalEditPart) getGraphicalViewer().getEditPartRegistry().get(object);

            if (editPart != null) {
                StructuredSelection eSelection = new StructuredSelection(editPart);
                getGraphicalViewer().setSelection(eSelection);
                // once selected if you want to get it so the
                // graphicalviewer scrolls to reveal the part on the
                // screen
                getGraphicalViewer().reveal(editPart);
            }
        }
    } else {
        super.selectionChanged(part, selection);
    }
}
```